# a4j:commandButton - Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'action' of null

Tags: xhtml

У меня есть *.xhtml файл, в котором есть <a4j:include viewId="... при нажатии на кнопку отображается эта вьюшка/модалка, в которой есть две кнопки "да" и "нет" (удалить файл или нет). Часть кода этой модалки есть на скрине. При нажатии на НЕТ, все срабатывает и окно закрывается. Но когда нажимаю ДА, то вылетает ошибка (на скрине). Бин у меня есть, и он прописан в xml, любые другие обращения к методам бина работают, но когда через экшн пытаюсь то падает. Два дня уже не могу найти причину. Пробовал ставить onclick, тогда отрабатывает onclick и потом серавно падает на action. Даже если удалить action серавно будет эта же ошибка. В гугле инфы по такой теме ноль. А ту что нашел не помогла.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Зачем связываться с прожектом, который "помер" в 2016 году? `The RichFaces project has reached end-of-life in June 2016`
У русских не то, что какой-то richfaces, но даже простой jsf не снискал популярности.
Кстати попробуйте заменить кнопки на простые из jsf `h:commandButton`
Либо что-то не то с ричфесом, которого никто не знает, либо Ваши бины и его методы называются вовсе не так, как Вы думаете

Comment: Это может быть и поддержка старого проекта. А вообще аудитория у jsf и у всех связанных с ней фреймворков вполне себе имелась и были нишы в которой они прекрасно и практически безальтернативно использовались. В общем то в той нишы, в которой они и задумывались. Не лендинги же с мелкими стартапами на них делать.

Comment: h:commandButton просто никак не реагирует и не выбрасывает ошибок. Связялся с проектом естестно не по своей воле=)